# Creating Javascript object with dot notation

Tags: javascript, object

I am learning Javascript and have a question regarding objects.  In a lesson I saw an object created like this:

```
var friends = {};

friends.john = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    fullName : function() {
       return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
};
```

Is john in friends.john a key who's value is what's in the curly braces? I do not understand when an object is first created with the dot notation vs. just putting everything into the curly braces to begin with.

Comment: Try `console.log` for debugging, you'll see the structure of your object.

Comment: I agree with @elclanrs statement; the best way to learn is working through your problem and resolving an answer by yourself.

Comment: You very well can add `john` property within definition of `friends`, the magic in `friends.john = {...}` is, that you can add properties to an object at any time after it has been defined.

Comment: `friends.john` (or `friends['john']`) is how you access/set a key after the object has been declared.  Setting it is the same as `friends = {john: {}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the code you have there is exactly equivalent to:

```
var friends = {
    john: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName : "Doe",
        id       : 5566,
        fullName : function() {
           return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        }
    }
};
```

There are a wide variety of ways to do the same thing in different ways in JavaScript. In this case, you can use either syntax, but you can only use the curly brace syntax to create a *new* object. To assign a property to an existing object, you would typically use the assignment syntax:

```
friends.john = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

john is a property of friends with the value of the object containing all of john's information. The dot notation is usually for use after the fact or in reference. You could have easily avoided it with this:

```
var friends = {
 john: {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  id       : 5566,
  fullName : function() {
   return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
 }
};
```

Comment: I fixed a syntax error for you.  You need the `:` inside the object, not `=` :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Yes thank you, that was a slight copy paste error :P

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to

```js
var friends = {
    john: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName : "Doe",
        id       : 5566,
        fullName : function() {
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        }
    }
};
```

and also to

```js
var friends = new Object();
friends.john = new Object();
friends.john.firstName = "John";
friends.john.lastName  = "Doe";
friends.john.id        = 5566;
friends.john.fullName  = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
code1:
var friends = {};
friends.john = {
firstName: "John",
lastName : "Doe",
id       : 5566,
fullName : function() {
   return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
};
```

here code1 is equivalent to code2:

```
 code2
var friends = {
john: {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    fullName : function() {
       return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
};
```

so if you run below statement both give the same result i.e. "John Doe"

> alert(friends.john.fullName());

Note: dot notation is used to access object property.in your case friends is a object where John is a property of friends and the things in a curly braces is John value.

Comment: @Andy may this help you :)